# DDD aggregate design example with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: many-to-many, aggregate, domain-driven-design

I would like to run through a modelling exercise to try and understand DDD a little better, specifically in the cases where there is a many-to-many relationship

Lets take an example of Xbox users and their achievements.

If you are not familiar this is the background:
Each game on Xbox has achievements.
User will have a list of games they own/have played and they can unlock achievements for these games.

There is a many-to-many relationship here as a user can have many games, and a game can have many users.

Without going further, there is definitely two aggregate roots here. User and game.
The game aggregate root has a list of achievements.

My confusion comes in with tracking the progress of a user for a specific game.
for instance what games they have, and what achievements they have for each game.

In a typical CRUD design it might look something like this:
[image]

**How would you now model this is DDD?**

User Game and User Achievement will have information regarding the progress of each.

This is a solution i currently think, but is it right?

[image]
User and game are both aggregate roots.

The progress of a game and it's individual achievements also seems to be connected and I would say that this is its own aggregate root. This is because like game and it's achievements, it potentially has a transaction boundary. When you progress on a game's achievement, this could effect the game's progress (e.g. unlocking an achievement would up the total game's gamerscore achieved.)

I keep hearing that you want to resolve many-to-many relationship, which is usually fine, but here, the relationship has its own data, and I don't think this relationship belongs to either.

You might be able to argue that you would put this on the user aggregate, but my concern is that it adds weight to that user aggregate and there is no reason for it to be there.
I don't think there is any transaction boundaries and I don't like the though of having to load all the user's games when you want to load it. Even if this was lazy loaded, I am concerned it might cause concurrency issues?

This is why I think the many to many relationship here is valid, and why a new aggregate root might be appropriate.

Also is the name user game progress even correct. Knowing the domain, what might you suggest?

Thank you, any help is massively appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for here is [Domain Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation). From the Microsoft documentation:

> Use domain events to explicitly implement side effects of changes
>   within your domain. In other words, and using DDD terminology, use
>   domain events to explicitly implement side effects across multiple
>   aggregates. Optionally, for better scalability and less impact in
>   database locks, use eventual consistency between aggregates within the
>   same domain.

The "progress of game" does not look to be an aggregate root to me. To update the "progress of game" you can raise a domain event such as "User_Moved" from your `User` aggregate and similar event from your `Game` aggregate. You can then subscribe to these events to update the game progress. Also, since Domain Events are in-memory you can achieve this within a single transaction.

Comment: So i am aware of events. But I don't they will resolve my issue. Events will come as a reaction to commands and is a way to notify others aggregates that something has happened.
I think there is a little bit of confusion, as game has two meanings here. There is a game in a global sense and specifically for the user. The game aggregate root is its own thing. It has not relation to the user. It isn't related to the user. Its the progress. So that progress is unique to each user.
So in a sense there is game and a user's game, if that makes sense

Comment: So to clerify, domain events are going to be raise for events in the system, but it is not the responsibility of game to keep track of user's progress. game is a standalone concept. 
if game were to track progress for each user, then you could have a list of x many users progress records, which is not scalable or fitting because there is not invariant that is trying to be kept consistent between all user's progress for a given game

Comment: If I understand you correctly, essentially you can have a separate `UserGameProcess` as a  Domain Object with `User` as an Aggregate. In your `User` Aggregate you would have a method such as `UpdateGameProgress` which may take Game Id as a parameter along with relevant parameters. The `UpdateGameProgress` then can call a corresponding method in `UserGameProgress` to update the game progress.. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Yer so this is where my concern comes in. There are two issues I see with that. The first is that it would cause a large cluster aggregate. A user can have 100's of games. An each game can also have a large quantity of achievements (as in user's progress for a game and achievements for it). 
We want to avoid large cluster aggregates, even if we use lazy loading.
Also the second things is that, there is no need for the user to contain their game progress because there is no transnational invariant that we are trying to keep consistent. It can be eventual. This is why I think to keep the m-m

Comment: *I think* I understand what you mean, having a separate aggregate may just help here. You can then have your Domain Events talk to those aggregates.  If these aggregates do not need to be committed in the same transaction, I would probably put a new message in queue in the domain event listener to update the game process as a separate transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to find an authoritative answer to your question that is more specific than "it depends".

For instance - suppose the game was chess, and we want to award an achievement when a player has one at least once with each color.  That's not going to be the responsibility of a "game" aggregate; we can see that immediately from the fact that the life cycles don't line up.

One quick way to sketch this suggests that we might have games raising "domain events" to announce wins, and then a little state machine that uses wins as inputs an announces awards, and then some report that lists all awards for a specific player id.

The state machine, and the accompanying domain logic that takes in wins and emits awards is probably an aggregate all by itself - one instance for each player.

The report - which combines this award with others for the same player... well, aside from some plumbing details that seems pretty anemic, unless you need to do something clever to show only "recent" awards, or something similar.

A good talk that explores these ideas: [All Our Aggregates Are Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzvQSuYd5I), by Mauro Servienti.

> If you were to come at this initially, this "player awards" aggregate could either be its own aggregate or could be a list of awards under the player.

It certainly could be a list of awards within the player aggregate.  But - assuming the analysis above is correct - the list of awards doesn't influence, and isn't influenced by, any other changes to player.

There's one list (which might be empty) for every player, and you'll want to be able to retrieve a specific player's list using the player id, but these conditions alone do *not* constrain us to consider the list a part of the player aggregate.

Comment: So I understand in your example that the player awards would not be on the game. Clearly it doesn't belong there as it is not a child of the game, it instead only requires to listen to game events, to potentially unlock the awards for the player.
This underlying is a many-to-many. players-awards, but the aggregate makes that a one-to-many instead. In your case, you seem to be using an aggregate to manage a list of awards.
If you were to come at this initially, this "player awards" aggregate could either be its own aggregate or could be a list of awards under the player.